# Sorting an array of object depending on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays like these:

```
objects = [Obj1, Obj2, Obj3];
scores  = [10,200,15];
```

with objects[i] corresponding to its score in scores[i].

I need to sort the objects array in a descending order, depending on their relative scores.

Any idea how to do that efficiently in jQuery/javascript ?
Thank you for your help !

Comment: It would probably be better to join them together as a single object and then sort them.

Comment: Do you also want scores sorted?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to keep the scores as a property of the object it belongs to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan suggests, probably the best approach is to join the values together and then separate them afterward if desired:

```
// produces [{score: 10,  value: Obj1}, 
//           {score: 200, value: Obj2},
//           {score: 15,  value: Obj3}]
var joined = objects.map(function (el, i) {
    return { score: scores[i], value: el };
});

// rearranges joined array to:
//          [{score: 200, value: Obj2},
//           {score: 15,  value: Obj3},
//           {score: 10,  value: Obj1}]
joined.sort(function (l, r) { return r.score - l.score; });

// produces [Obj2, Obj3, Obj1]
var sorted = joined.map(function (el) { return el.value; });
```